# Mounting home networking gear on pegboard

Tags: pegboard

I've got a panel of pegboard in a closet that I'd like to use to mount my router, cable modem and other similar gear. Are there accessories that either screw into the holes themselves, or are small enough where a typical device will fit over them? Standard accessories are too thick, and don't fit through the mounting holes of the network gear.

Comment: Your best bet might be to 3D-print "adapters" to hang them. Each brand and even each individual bit of equipment will have different mounting holes (or sometimes none at all), so measuring and making pegs/hooks/etc that will hold *your* gear may be the way to go. If you don't have a 3D printer, look at www.3dhubs.com

Comment: If the router and modem mount by resting on screw heads, you could just screw into the pegboard holes with a 1/2" correctly-sized screw (depending on the material of the pegboard, and so long as you don't mind damaging the holes a bit). It won't hold much weight, but that equipment is generally pretty light.

Comment: There are pegboard shelf supports, which you can then rest a small piece of wood on, forming a small shelf (or two or three) for your gear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have all my networking gear (router, switch, PoE injector) secured with industrial strength adhesive velcro and zip ties. I imagine if you can take the time to fish the zip ties through the holes of the peg board this would work pretty well (the green lines are zip ties):

[image]

Comment: Or use them to attach hardware to common pegboard hooks and bars.